# Blackberry vs Outlook html rendering

Tags: html, blackberry, outlook

Earlier on I had a problem trying to display html in Outlook 2007. It appeared that Outlook didn't support the div structure I had used to create my table.

I reverted back to the 'old school' table structure using td and tr. However, this works in Outlook 2007 but when I open the email on my blackberry the columns have floated left and it doesnt not appear like a table anymore.

My test html is:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>Y</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Overall</td>
                <td>207,890</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>B</td>
                <td>100,568</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>C</td>
                <td>107,322</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @albert, I removed it anyway- will edit my Q

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Newsletters ARE old school :)

You're code is basically correct but for Best Practice you should at least

- "reset" cellspacing, cellpadding and border of the table to 0;
- specify width/height of the cells;
- add the so called bug-fixes in the header; inside a style tag, insert the following css:

> ```
> .ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}
> .ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
> img{margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;}
> a img{margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;}
> ```

This would improve your rendering across the main email clients.